# interChange-Framework - EMP default Datalist sort

Tags: c#

In a Datalist inside an EntityMaintenancePanel the default sorting column is the first one, how can I select another column to be used as default for sorting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Override OnInit Method and add the following sort expression:

```
//Set Default Sort by DescriptionParent
string sort = this.Datalist.GetSortExpression();
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(sort))
   this.Datalist.SetSortExpression(SORT_EXPT_NAME, iC.WebUI.WebControls.DataList.SortOrder.ASC);
```